# zap not showing correct GET api in summery report

Tags: zap

I am using ZAP in my security testing project.  its really help me a lot. but I face a problem that I and our project manager also want to know,  "our login request is a POST request. than why zap showing a security vulnerability of login request by changeing the name *Post* to **GET** request at the summary report?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that ZAP has reported a potential vulnerability on a page with a GET request is not at all surprising.
In this case the ZAP spider was used - this will request all of the links it finds using a GET request and only make POST requests when it finds suitable forms.
Whether the specific vulnerability should really have been reported on a POST request is impossible to say without more information.

For more info see the discussion on the ZAP User Group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zaproxy-users/TGrlqPFc7FI/wSqi9wFrCgAJ